# Why the error? %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python

I am trying to run a simple program but is giving the following error. I am running it on PyCharm, Python 3.8 and Windows. The code runs without error if I don't import Pandas.

```
import pandas

def print_hi(name):
    # Use a breakpoint in the code line below to debug your script.
    print(f'Hi, {name}')  # Press Ctrl+F8 to toggle the breakpoint.


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pmodi/Documents/Python3/Trial123/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Users\pmodi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Users\pmodi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\pmodi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\pmodi\Anaconda3\envs\Trial123\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It’s possible that dlopen is trying to open a dynamic library which has a binary that wasn’t compiled for Windows (maybe Linux instead).

It may also be that dlopen is trying to open something that isn’t even a compiled compiled binary at all (just a plain old python text file if the extension is .py).

Comment: Did you just install `pandas`, or has it worked with other code in the past? - If you just installed it, how did you do so?  @AlexWalczak has a point.  It could be that you somehow installed a package that was built for a different OS environment, even just a different build of Windows.  If `pandas` used to work, is there something else that you did recently to reconfigure Python that might have caused this?